# WCF ReceiveTimeout infinite

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wcf

I'm using a "wsHttpBinding" with a reliable session. I'd like to keep the client-server connection endless open. Therefore I need to set the ReceiveTimeout to "infinite". Has the "ReceiveTimeout"  an other purpose (e.g. client crash detection; detecting a hanging request; etc) or can I set it to "infinite" without problems?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReceiveTimeout is to ensure that clients can't use/block resources over an undefined timespan. So it's up to you to decide if that could happen.